# Result as object where key is each value in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to figure out how it is possible to define the result of `primaryKey` where it is an object and each key is a value from the array `$primaryKey`. However I am not sure how this can be done. I don't think I can use `keyof this.$primaryKey` as I tried and get an error. How (if possible) can this be done?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKUCWBbAhlRAaWETgF44BvOAbQGsSAuOBxCAMzgFkIATYADYA6ACRgseAsUQBdZgBEAQgGFBAuAF8AUFtCRYcXACMAzjCi4AxvEsDcJk9z6C4oGMAB2vR0qpa4cGAArkYCmJZwYhL4RExwZlgeAOY0MuS0AOS4GQA0cBlGGTI6AcGh4XBJwPDiODHSABQAlMwYdVIkVHD+AXBQ1UFQHl24zACMAEwAzHlGzAAsAKwAbJo92hpAA)

```js
export type PrimaryKey = { [key: keyof Model.$primaryKey]: DBCell }

export abstract class Model extends DB {
  public $primaryKey: string[] = ['a', 'b']

  public get primaryKey(): PrimaryKey { 
    return { a: 123, b: 456 }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are asking from the phrasing and code example you have provided. Please try to rewrite this question in a clearer manner.

Comment: I am trying to type hint the result of `primaryKey` as an object where the keys are the values of of the array, so TypeScript will know that the result is an object where each key is the value of the array in this case `a` and `b`.

Comment: Ok that's way clearer now! Interesting i'll play around with it see if i get anything.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get `PrimaryKey` defined with the following changes:

```js
public $primaryKey = ['a', 'b'] as const;
```

`as const` causes the type of `$primaryKey` to be inferred as `['a', 'b']` (a tuple of literal string types) instead of a plain `string[]`.

You can then turn this into `'a' | 'b'` using index types:

```js
Model["$primaryKey"][number]
```

First set of brackets extracts the tuple type, the second set turns it into a union of its values.

From there it's trivial to create an object using the `Record` utility type:

```js
export type PrimaryKey = Record<Model["$primaryKey"][number], DBCell>
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCICEDCEA2PkDeAvgFBwBGAzmFImMgjnJZWuoaSRAB4AOA9lHpgAnrxQAFKMAC2cKCIDSEEcgC8yAEoQEggCYAeALL89uANoAiACS9pchcpGWAuuZABXGeWguANGzYeAB8JFx8gvQU1LQI9IzMrCZm+DyQIHqsGIQkyMi8HuQ4wAjItvbySirqyOYA5HB1AXXkdS7IzAz8INQA3GF5BUUlyADmEPR2spVOABQAlABcyFLTjtUEyLl5yFATHlAghB3LAIwATADMAeTLACwArABsyKR5pERAA)

Comment: Somewhat okay... I don't want to have to assign it as a const though, as this is an abstract class so the value will change

Comment: If you want static type safety, then you'll need to encode primary keys in the type of each implementation somehow. First thing that comes to mind is generics, but maybe there's another way. Using `string[]` discards the information about actual values in the array, it won't be possible to construct an object with the keys verified at compile time.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without the `as const` @GetOffMyLawn